# Drawing realistic 2d waves with SDL2 and Rust

Tags: 2d, rendering, sdl2, simulations

I am making a very simple 2d topdown sailing simulator with [Rust](http://rust-lang.org) and [rust-sdl2](http://github.com/AngryLawyer/rust-sdl2). I am having a very hard time figuring out how I should implement wave rendering. My current idea is to use a `Vec<Spring>` and render all of the wave shading on top of these springs. But I have no idea how this rendering should be done. Here is an image which mostly represents the effect I want:

[image]

Most questions here are to do with OpenGL which I have no experience with and don't understand at all. Any pseudocode would be particularly helpful!

Comment: Can you please provide use with an image of how it should look?

Comment: Frankly if you have no experience with OpenGL, AND you're learning Rust, AND you're learning SDL I would say you _might just_ be aiming a bit high at this point. Try to go for a simpler solution for your waves.

Having said that, learning to write pixel shaders for a 2D projection is pretty simple.

Comment: Do you want to do the rendering in OpenGL or using SDL2's rendering framework?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 I would like to use SDL2's rendering framework as that is the framework I am the most familiar with.